Does the convex conjugate reverse little o relations
This is a better version of a previous question I had.
Let $f,g : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be convex functions with both $x =o(f(x))$ and $x=o(g(x))$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.
Then their convex conjugates $f^*,g^*: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ are (well-)defined by
$$
    f^*(y) = \sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-f(x)\}
$$
$$
    g^*(y) = \sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-g(x)\}
$$
Note that if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$, then $g^*(y) \leq f^*(y)$ for all $y$.
If additionally $f(x) = o(g(x))$, does $g^*(y) = o(f^*(y))$ also hold? (All little o relations are at $+\infty$.)
This seems hard to prove using the definitions.
One would need to show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $y_n$ such that for all $y \geq y_n$ holds that
$$
\frac{\sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-g(x)\}}{\sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-f(x)\}}\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$

This property does not hold.
Take
$$
f(x) = e^\frac{x}{2}-1
$$
$$
g(x) = e^x-1
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} 
= \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{2} }
= 0
,
$$
so $f(x)=o(g(x))$.
We also have
$$
f^*(y) = 2y \log(2y) - 2y + 1
$$
$$
g^*(y) = y \log(y) - y + 1
$$
so
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{g^*(y)}{f^*(y)} = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0.
$$
In particular $g^*(y)\neq o(f^*(y))$.
